# angular directive display order

Tags: css, angular, angular-directive

I have 3 UL inside a div. 2 UL contain a directive that checks if the user is authenticated or not. like so:

```
<div class="language-options">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>
                <select box></select box>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Show this for logged out users -->
    <ul *appShowAuthed="false">
        <li>
            <a>
                Sign in
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                Sign up
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Show this for logged in users -->
    <ul *appShowAuthed="true">
        <li>
            <a>
                Home
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                <i></i>&nbsp;New Article
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                <i></i>&nbsp;Settings
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>
                <img [src]="currentUser.image" *ngIf="currentUser.image" class="user-pic" /> {{ currentUser.username }}
            </a>
        </li>    
    </ul>
</div>
```

What is happening is that although my language-options select box is before in the html code then the other 2 ULs it displays after them in the page:

```
[ Sign in | Sign up ] [ select box ]
```

It seems that due to the directive execution that the html code takes longer to render and as suchs displays before the language-options.

How an I set the language-options UL to display before the Sign in | Sign up? see below:

```
[ select box ] [ Sign in | Sign up ]
```

Comment: It's probably a CSS thing. Can you replicate your issue in a StackBlitz or something similar please?

Comment: Correct, this is related to float: rigth;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to the css: float: right.